# The standard way to design a full fledged tagging system with interrelationships among tags

Tags: database, tags, many-to-many, rdbms

I am working on this web platform where there are multiple tags associated with different objects like people, company, Articles.

I am following the RDBMS approach where i have:

A Tag model which is associated with all other above mentioned models through Many to Many fields. Things are working fine upto here.

Now, I want to create some kind of inter-relationship between tags so as to suggest related tags when user selects one tag the way quora or medium does when you are filling up your interests (**not** based on text).

One way would be to create a many to many field with self and then store the many to many objects whenever somebody selects two or more tags and then counting the instances when trying to figure out which tag are similar and predicting how closely two different tags can be associated.

What I am concerned about is that it could be too much taxing on the database.

Is there a better way to handle this. Please share thoughts.

Comment: You could use a graph DB-- titan, orientDB, neo4j to efficiently store the relationships.

Comment: Ok, I would count that as an option. But I am trying to get it done in some way using MySQL right now.